# Transclusion of existing answers in new questions

Tags: discussion

Programming languages have different gotchas. For example, there are heaps of questions about Bash scripts not working because they use DOS newlines or don't quote strings. Many such questions all have the same cause, and therefore the same answer, but they aren't duplicates because the *symptoms* are very different. Or at least they don't seem to be treated as duplicates by the rest of the community, judging by their survival rate.

In the best case such questions are answered by essentially copying the best answer which already exists from another question with the same cause, including a link to the original answer. Some answers just copy the original answer or paste a link with no explanation, both of which are likely to solve OP's problem but not very good for the quality of the site (the former because of lack of connectivity between related issues and a lack of updates in case of fixes or changes in best practice, the latter because getting to the answer shouldn't require clicking links).

What if we could **[transclude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion) a specific version of an *existing* answer as an answer to a new question**?

1. The new answer would link to the original Q&A automatically, so symptoms with the same cause/issues with the same solution would be easily discoverable.
2. Both the original respondent and the new one would be awarded reputation.

Some issues:

1. How do you distribute score between the person who linked the original answer and the original answerer?
2. What if later versions of the original answer correct errors?
3. Is there a risk of answers becoming overly general, to be applicable to as many questions as possible, while not being as clear as possible for the case at hand?

I'm doubtful that this is feasible, and I have no idea if it could be implemented fairly, but it seems like some way of linking Q&A entries by their *causes* rather than their *symptoms* would be a useful concept. It seems to fit the "teach someone to fish" spirit of SO.

Answer (score 6):

> Many such questions all have the same cause, and therefore the same answer, but they aren't duplicates because the symptoms are very different.

They *are* duplicates.  If the cause is the same, but the error message is different, then they are duplicate questions.  It is when the answer is the same, *but the cause is different,* that they are not duplicates.

If you find that you have difficulty matching an entire category of questions about broken Bash scripts that have the same essential cause, create a Canonical/Reference question/answer pair that describes this cause and how to troubleshoot it, and begin closing those questions as dupes of the Canonical/Reference question.